# Can I specify multiple files in a git commit command that have already been staged?

Tags: git

I have many files that are already added to the index but I would like to commit only some of them AT FIRST because the review tool works on commits. If I simply do a git commit, I think I will get ALL the files. I think I can do: git commit file1 file2 file3 and if this is true, I would like to be able to store a very long list of files in file and specify this as input to the commit command. Alternatively, I would like to be able to commit many times with a single commit id. I do not want to unstage some files because there are hundreds of files in the index, only some of which are important to be reviewed.

Is there a safe way to force this to happen? Once that is done, I will then do a commit to get the remaining files, if possible.

EDIT: Bottom line, yes you can specify some subset of staged files, a partial commit. But in the case of a merge which caused many files to change and be staged and only some of which I wanted to be committed for review (the rest later) you *can't* do this; Git will not allow a partial commit during a merge. If I am wrong, I am sure someone will let me know.

EDIT: I attempted the "xargs" (as suggested by Edmundo) solution and got the error: fatal: cannot do a partial commit during a merge.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the list on a file, you could use xargs to get them to be passed as the parameters of the git commit: `cat file-of-files.txt | xargs git commit -m "Here's a few files to be committed"`

Comment: and yes.... you could have 1000 files on index, if you provide 2 files on commit, only those two files will be committed. The only thing that I think will happen is that they will be taken as they are on the working tree, not the index (which is not the same for all cases).

Answer (score 2):

> I think I can do: git commit file1 file2 file3

Yes, but you must understand that git will ignore staged hunks and commit these files wholly. This is important if you staged parts of files using `git add -p`.

> Alternatively, I would like to be able to commit many times with a single commit id.

Impossible. Every time you amend a commit its SHA-1 id changes. But if you use gerrit for review it doesn't matter: gerrit appends its own id to commit message on the first commit to link amended commit to the same review; do not remove this id when ammending the commit.

Comment: Your point about staged hunks: do you mean that if a single file was broken into parts and the parts are all staged? If so, these are all single files, like .java or .xml or .json files, not broken up. Or am I misunderstanding hunk as being a partial file?

Comment: A "hunk" is a part of file staged with `git add -p`. If you staged your files wholly you don't need to worry about staged and unstaged hunks. Go on with `git commit file1 2 3`.

Answer (score 0):

As both [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44791260/1256452) and [Edmundo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44791217/1256452) answered, yes, you can do this, but you need to be aware of how Git actually makes commits.

The normal, standard setup for Git is that there are *three copies* of every file associated with the current commit:

```
HEAD     index    work-tree
-----    -----    ---------
file1    file1    file1
file2    file2    file2
  :        :        :
fileN    fileN    fileN
```

The copy in the commit (`HEAD`) is read-only: it can never be changed.  The copy in the index is read/write, but otherwise stored in a special Git-only format.  The copy in the work-tree is read/write and is stored in the normal everyday form that your computer uses for files.

When you run `git add`, Git copies the work-tree version of a file into the index.  Let's say you changed `file2` somewhat:

```
HEAD     index    work-tree
-----    -----    ---------
file1    file1    file1
file2    file2    file2*
  :        :        :
fileN    fileN    fileN
```

The asterisk here means that the contents of *this* version of `file2` are different.

Running `git add file2` copies `file2` from the work-tree into the index:

```
HEAD     index    work-tree
-----    -----    ---------
file1    file1    file1
file2    file2*   file2*
  :        :        :
fileN    fileN    fileN
```

(Aside: note that running `git reset file2` copies `file2` from `HEAD` into the index, removing the change from the index while leaving it in the work-tree.)

When you run an ordinary `git commit`, Git packages up whatever is in the index *right now* and makes the new commit using those files.  So if you have modified `file2`, then copied the new file into the index, then run `git commit`, you get the modified `file2` in the new commit.  The unmodified `file1`, `file3`, ..., `fileN` also go into the new commit.

When you run, e.g., `git commit file1 file2`, though, Git does something special.

#### Committing with file arguments makes a temporary extra index

Let's make a change to file `file3` but *not* run `git add` yet.

```
HEAD     index    work-tree
-----    -----    ---------
file1    file1    file1
file2    file2*   file2*
file3    file3    file3*
  :        :        :
fileN    fileN    fileN
```

If you run `git commit file3` now, for instance, Git starts by copying something into a temporary index.

There are several things Git could sensibly copy here, to get the starting point for the temporary index.  What it actually uses depends on flag arguments:

- `git commit --include file3`: Git copies the *existing* index to the temporary index.  This gets you `file1`, `file2*`, `file3`, and so on.  Note that we get the *new* `file2` here, not the old one.
- `git commit --only file3`: Git copies the *`HEAD` commit* to the temporary index.  This gets you `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, and so on.  Note that we get the *old* (HEAD-version) `file2` here.

Next, Git adds the files listed on the command line.  This replaces the temporary index's `file3` with `file3*`.

Now Git makes the commit, using the temporary index.

Last, Git *copies some things from the temporary index* back into the regular (ordinary) index.  Specifically, it copies back all the files you listed on the command line—so `file3*` goes into the regular index.

#### Partially staged files

What phd is referring to is the use of `git add -p`, `git reset -p`, or the ability to do:

```
$ make-change-to file2
$ git add file2
$ make-different-change-to file2
```

Now you have something we might describe as:

```
HEAD     index    work-tree
-----    -----    ---------
file1    file1    file1
file2    file2*   file2†
  :        :        :
fileN    fileN    fileN
```

That is, there are now three *different* versions of `file2` active all at the same time: the original unmodified `HEAD` version, the first modified version stored in the index, and the second modified version stored in the work-tree.

If you `git commit file2`, Git will make a new temporary index, copy the work-tree `file2†` version into that temporary index, commit from the temporary index, and then ***copy the temporary index `file2†` file over the regular index `file2*` file***.  The effect is that you lose the middle version entirely.

Comment: What is intended is to commit some subset of the added files, get the commit id and use this in the review. The review could result in comments that require changes to the reviewed files. Are you describing a situation that could result in a problem in this scenario?

Comment: @Jeff: If the normal index does not have a *different* version of those files than the work-tree, and you are careful to use `--only` (well, it's the default, so maybe I should say "careful not to use `--include`"), then you should be fine.